# Passing an aggregate select expression to Dynamic Linq's GroupBy

Tags: entity-framework, dynamic-linq

I have simplified the following example from my code and hoping there's no obvious compilation errors because of it. Lets say I have the following entities (not what i actually have, please assume I have no EF or schema issues, this is just for example):

```
public class Company
{
  public string GroupProperty {get;set;}
  public virtual ICollection<PricingForm> PricingForms {get;set;}
}
public class PricingForm
{
  public decimal Cost {get;set;}
}
```

And I want to query like so:

```
IQueryable DynamicGrouping<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
{
  Expression<Func<Company, decimal?>> exp = c => c.PricingForms.Sum(fr => fr.Cost);
  string selector = "new (it.Key as Key, @0(it) as Value)";
  IQueryable grouping = query.GroupBy("it.GroupProperty", "it").Select(selector, exp);
  return grouping;
}
```

I get the following error when calling the groupby/select line:

```
System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: 'Argument list incompatible with lambda expression'
```

What type is "it" when grouped? I have tried using other expressions that assume it is an `IGrouping<string, Company>`, or a `IQueryable<Company>`, same error. I've tried just selecting "Cost" and moving the Sum() aggregate into the selector string (i.e. `Sum(@0(it)) as Value`) and always seem to get the same error.

I eventually tried something along the lines of:

```
Expression<Func<IEnumerable<Company>, decimal?>> exp = l => l.SelectMany(c => c.PricingForms).Sum(fr => fr.Cost);
```

However this one, I get farther but when attempting to iterate through the results I got a different error.

```
The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

So, with this dynamic grouping and injecting my own select expression, what should I assume the datatype of 'it' is? Will this even work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `it` is `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`, where `TKey` is dynamic based on the `keySelector` result type, and `TElement` is the element type of the input `IQueryable`. Luckily `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` inherits (is a) `IEnumerable<TElement>`, so as soon as you know the input element type, you can safely base selector on `IEnumerable<TElement>`.

In other words, the last attempt based on `Expression<Func<IEnumerable<Company>, decimal?>>` is correct.

The new error you are getting is because `@0(it)` generates [`Expression.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355170(v=vs.110).aspx) call which is not supported by EF. The easiest way to fix that is to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) `Expand` method:

```
Expression<Func<Company, decimal?>> exp = c => c.PricingForms.Sum(fr => fr.Cost);
string selector = "new (it.Key as Key, @0(it) as Value)";
IQueryable grouping = query.GroupBy("it.GroupProperty", "it").Select(selector, exp);

// This would fix the EF invocation expression error
grouping = grouping.Provider.CreateQuery(grouping.Expression.Expand());

return grouping;
```